# Accessing a field collection

Tags: theming

My content type uses a field collection (field_site_web) to allow users to enter multiple websites, consisting of a name (field_site_name) and an internet connection (field_link).

I want to use a `foreach()` loop to get those value, but I do not know how to access these fields. How can I do?

EDIT

how can I do to avoid the error in the line of the foreach? I tried so, but does not work:

```
if($fc_fields != false){
  // Extract the field collection item ids
  $ids = array();
  foreach ($fc_fields as $fc_field) {
    $ids[] = $fc_field['value'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The field collection is an entity in it's own right; the values stored against your node are a list of field collection item ids that you'll need to load manually to loop over. Something like this:

```
// Get the field collection items.
$fc_fields = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_field_collection_field');

// Extract the field collection item ids
$ids = array();
foreach ($fc_fields as $fc_field) {
  $ids[] = $fc_field['value'];
}

// Load up the field collection items
$items = field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids);

// Loop through the items and extract field values
foreach ($items as $item) {
  $link_fields = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $item, 'field_link');
  $link = array_shift($link_fields);
  $url = $link['url'];

  $site_name_fields = field_get_items('field_collection_item', $item, 'field_site_name');
  $site_name = array_shift($site_name_fields);
  $name = $site_name['value'];
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry, can i see how you manage to print the field_link and field_site_name?

Comment: I've updated the answer to extract both fields...basically you just need to `print $url` and `print $name` in the loop

Comment: I found this error: $ url = $ link ['value'];
thanks for your invaluable help!

Comment: See http://pixeljets.com/blog/writing-robust-code-uses-fields-drupal-7

Comment: how can I do to avoid the error in the line of the foreach?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in include() (line 140 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal5/sites/all/themes/myzen/templates/node.tpl.php).

Comment: Have you replaced `field_field_collection_field` with the real name of your field collection field?

Comment: yes, is field_site_web, but I can not even put any value for field collection...data must be shown only if they were inserted ..