# How to loop through fields from the Field Collection?

Tags: 7, entities

Here below is the code loading data present in the field collection.
$field_collection = entity_load('field_collection_item', $ids = FALSE);

In each field collection, there are many fields, i would like to loop through each fields
is there a way to do it? Any help?

Comment: What do you want to with them? You catch an array of objects in $field_collection and can loop through the array with php foreach.

Answer (score 9):

I'm current "fighting" width this module, too. I don't know if it is the correct/easiest way, but it works (for me).

First you have to load the ids of the field collection fields of the node:

```
$fc_fields = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image_teaser');

// Extract the field collection item ids
$ids = array();
foreach ($fc_fields as $fc_field) {
    $ids[] = $fc_field['value'];
}
```

I found the code above at [Accessing a field collection](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35355/accessing-a-field-collection) (a related question).

To iterate over all fields you can use the following code:

```
//Get the entities
$collections = field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids);

//Loop over the array - if you have more than one entity
for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($collections); $i++) {
    $collection = $collections [$i];

    //Iterate over all member vars of the FieldCollectionItemEntity object
    foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
        //Look for fields - there are some other class vars, too.
        if (strpos ($key, 'field') !== false) {
            //Search for textfields 
            if (isset($value['und']) && is_array($value ['und']) && isset($value['und'][0]['value'])) {
                print "Field ".$key." ".$value['und'][0]['value'];
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: Your ids loop can be replaced with this now : `$ids = array_column($fc_fields, 'value');` as per http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$fc_fields = field_info_instances('field_collection_item', $field_name);
```

This will probably help.

Comment: For further reference: This is the correct way to get the fields you use for your loop. You might have fields either not beginning with "field_" from custom modules or properties starting with "field_".

Answer (score 0):

The second iteration need to be in the below way. Because of the following reasons,

- The result of `field_collection_item_load_multiple` will not be 0 based array.
- For images the url will not be in the index **['und'][0]['value']**

  ```
  //Get the entities
  $collections = field_collection_item_load_multiple($ids);
  $loadedValues;
  //Loop over the array - if you have more than one entity
  $i = 0;
  foreach ($collections as $collection) {

      //Iterate over all member vars of the FieldCollectionItemEntity object
      foreach($collection as $key => $value) {
          //Look for fields - there are some other class vars, too.
          if (strpos ($key, 'field') !== false) {
              //Search for textfields 
              if (is_array($value) && isset($value['und']) && is_array($value ['und']) && (isset($value['und'][0]['value'])||isset($value['und'][0]['uri']))) {
                  // print "Field ".$key." ".$value['und'][0]['value'];
                  if(isset($value['und'][0]['value']))
                  {
                      $loadedValues[$i][$key] = $value['und'][0]['value'];
                  }
                  else if($value['und'][0]['uri'])
                  {
                      $loadedValues[$i][$key] = $value['und'][0]['uri'];
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      $i++;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

That code by @AlxVallejo will give you the field collection structure (an array of field definitions). You can use that to loop through your entity after that. So, developing on is suggestion:

```
$fc_fields = field_info_instances('field_collection_item', $field_name);
$field_list = array_keys($fc_fields);

foreach ($field_list as $key) {
  // access your current field using $field_collection_entity->{$key} 
}
```